# How to implement For-loop logic in Spinner (android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, for-loop

I have 6 repetitive codes and I just want to use for-loop logic.
I tried to use "getIdentifier" and "findViewById" But I failed.

```
 val sb_spinner_secret_p1: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.sb_secret1)  
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.secret, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            sb_spinner_secret_p1.adapter = adapter
        }
```

I tried this but it never works

```
for(i in 1..7){
            val sb_spinner = "sb_spinner_secret_p$i"
            val sbsecret = "sb_secret$i"
            val sb_spinner_resId = resources.getIdentifier(sb_spinner,"id", packageName)
            val sbsecret_resId = resources.getIdentifier(sbsecret,"id", packageName)
        }
```

Comment: Maybe put your resource ids in an array and loop through that?

Comment: Why are you trying to get an identifier from `sb_spinner` that is a `String`?